# Exported FBX won’t write most textures unless embedded

Tags: texturing, export, image, .fbx, file-format

I am exporting a model to FBX. There are a few objects and a few materials in it. All data is packed into the model, including textures.

When exporting, I choose Path Mode > Copy, because I want to write all textures into image files, but only one of them is written.

What am I doing wrong?

Shaders are as simple as possible - only principled BSDF with image textures or base colors.
Maybe this is related to the fact that I’m using alpha version of Blender 3.0, but I also tried copying the objects into a new scene in Blender 2.92 stable version, and the issue persists.
I attach the model saved in v2.92.

Don’t mind weird looking meshes. I deleted most of them to make the file smaller.

These are my export settings:

[image]

Later, I found a partial solution:

I ticked “Embed Textures” next to Path Mode setting, and all textures got written into FBX file.
Though, this is not an ideal solution, because not all software supports textures embedded inside model file, e.g. SketchUp won’t import them without a paid plugin.

I believe Blender should be able to export FBX and write all relevant textures to separate files.

Here you’ll find the Blend:

https://we.tl/t-3xsmkzzkIZ

https://drive.google.com/file/d/148qUt6AkQPAhDYPwsh4KrGXvPbuaPg17/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, texture files tend to not be correctly included if they are not in a relative path and in the same folder or subfolder relative to the .blend.

A fast and simple way to fix this:

- File > External Data > Pack Ressources
- Save file
- File > External Data > Unpack Resources > Write files to current directory
- Save file

This will essentially copy all your files into subfolders next to your .blend. Texture files will be in a `texture` folder.

After this, exporting FBX "magically" includes all textures. Te fbx will have its own folder of textures though, don't forget to ship it with the fbx file!

Comment: So this is actually a bug in Blender, isn't it? When texture maps are part of Blender file, they won't properly export with FBX. They have to be saved in separate files, and only then can be written next to FBX.

Comment: I think you could just pack in the blend file and export right away. But I personally don't recommand working on a blend with packed data, it makes every data access more complicated, I reserve that for packaging.